# How to find distance from depth image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect, distance, depth

I am having same problem like this link:
[Why kinect color and depth won't align correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050285/why-kinect-color-and-depth-wont-align-correctly)

I tried to use 3 bit shifting and got the same result as it stated in answer. I overlay RGB image using edge detection using canny based on depth image.

I also did this:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Working-with-Depth-Data

But still did not give distance. 
Perhaps you can help me by telling me what to do with this shifting?

Best.