# Kinect depth and color image

Tags: opencv, kinect

I got a little problem with the depth map to point color map,
i simply threshold the nearst depth (about 70-80cm), then i bitwise and the thresholded depth image to corresponding color map,

```
Mat depthFilter(Mat depth,Mat color){
Mat I;
depth.convertTo(I, CV_8UC1, 255.0 / 4096.0);
unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(I.data);
for (int i = 0; i < I.cols; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < I.rows; j++){
        int pixel = input[I.cols*j + i];
        if (!(pixel <52 && pixel >42)){
            input[I.cols*j + i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            input[I.cols*j + i] = 255;
        }
    }
}
cvtColor(color, color, CV_BGR2GRAY);
bitwise_and(I, color, I);
return I;
```

}
(I'm using OpenCvKinect, which uses OpenNi and OpenCv)
But my problem is, the point's are not the same.. I think i need to find some relation between two images, but how :)!

http://postimg.org/image/hyxt25bwd/

Comment: It seems the depthmap and RGB image are not registered, try enabling the registered mode on the Kinect.

Answer (score 0):

I would see [Why kinect color and depth won't align correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050285/why-kinect-color-and-depth-wont-align-correctly) as they are having a similar problem in matlab. The answer suggest to use OpenNI's [AlternateViewCapability](http://kinectcar.ronsper.com/docs/openni/classxn_1_1_alternative_view_point_capability.html) class to align the images. This is the documentation from the older version of OpenNI (1.5) as I cannot find the 2.0 documentation for C++, but there is probably a similar method. The images on that answer show the difference the shift made.

The code is essentially

```
depth.GetAlternativeViewPointCap().SetViewPoint(image); //depth is depth generator
                                                        //image is color generator
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already solved the problem of alignment, however this has been implemented within [OpenCVKinect](https://github.com/masad801/OpenCVKinect) Wrappers that you are already using.

To acquire aligned Depth and Color images from Kinect, you need to use `setMode` function as follows:

```
setMode(C_MODE_DEPTH | C_MODE_COLOR | C_MODE_ALIGNED);
```